# Is there anyway to locate the configuration file in another project?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, configuration-files, edmx

I'm using entity framework. When an edmx file is generated, the connection string appears in the app.config file.

Is it possible to locate the configuration file in another project? Or, let the edmx file use another project's app.config's connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET application uses configuration file of executed assembly. .NET IIS hosted application use web.config. Simply move your connection string to the correct configuration file. That is a correct solution to do that. Otherwise you will have to open another configuration file manually, get the connection string and pass it to context in your code.